# Slow query after big INSERT in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, batch-processing, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-performance

We are using Postgres 9.2 in RedHat. We have a table similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE BULK_WI (
    BULK_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    USER_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CHUNK_ID INTEGER,
    STATE VARCHAR(16),
    CONSTRAINT BASE_BULK_WI_PK PRIMARY KEY(BULK_ID,USER_ID)
);
CREATE INDEX BASE_BULK_WI_IDX01 ON BULK_WI(STATE, CHUNK_ID);
```

As part of a batch job, we first add a number of rows to the table using a new BULK_ID. All new records have CHUNK_ID = NULL, STATE = 'PENDING'. The insert is between 500K and 1.5M rows. The size of the table when this happens is over 15M records.

After the insert, we start processing the table in chunks. To do this, we first select a number of items for the next chunk, then process them. Selecting the items happens with the following query:

```
UPDATE BASE_BULK_WI wi SET wi.STATE = 'PROCESSING', wi.CHUNK_ID = $1 
WHERE wi.STATE='PENDING' AND wi.BULK_ID = $2 
AND wi.USER_ID IN 
    (SELECT USER_ID FROM BASE_BULK_WI WHERE BULK_ID = $3 
     AND CHUNK_ID IS NULL AND STATE='PENDING' LIMIT $4 FOR UPDATE)
```

**$1** increases with each chunk iteration, **$2** and **$3** are always the same (the BULK_ID just inserted), **$4** is usually between 2,000 and 10,000.

The problem is that the first few chunks take a long time to be updated. For example, for a limit of 2000 most of the updates occur in under 1 second, while the first few ones take over 2 minutes.

We are trying to understand why this happens and how to fix it. After reading the documentation:

> To ensure data page consistency, the first modification of a data page after each checkpoint results in logging the entire page content.

we believe it's related to the checkpoints and the WAL, but we've been unable to pin it down.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It might help to add your postgre.conf file maybe some of your settings are low for the work load you are throwing at it.

Comment: @JustBob `postgresql.conf` perhaps? I've never heard of this "postgre.conf" :-P

Answer (score 6):

#### [`ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-analyze.html)

The [autovacuum daemon](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) also runs `ANALYZE` automatically, but it takes some time to kick in. If you run `UPDATE` immediately after a huge `INSERT`, make sure to run `ANALYZE` *in between* to update statistics, or the query planner may make bad choices.

#### `FROM` clause instead of `IN`

`IN` is notoriously slow with large subqueries. This might perform better:

```
UPDATE base_bulk_wi wi
SET   wi.state = 'PROCESSING'
    , wi.chunk_id = $1 
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, bulk_id 
    FROM   base_bulk_wi
    WHERE  bulk_id = $3 
    AND    chunk_id IS NULL
    AND    state = 'PENDING'
    LIMIT  $4
    FOR    UPDATE
    ) x 
WHERE wi.bulk_id = x.bulk_id
AND   wi.user_id = x.user_id;
```

#### Indexes

A [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) like this should be the optimum for your case:

```
CREATE INDEX base_bulk_wi_partial_idx01 ON bulk_wi(chunk_id)
WHERE state = 'PENDING' AND chunk_id IS NULL;
```

For best performance, create this index *after* your `INSERT`. If it already exists, it might help to drop before and recreate after.

One might think it's a good idea to include `bulk_id` in this index to allow for an **index-only scan** in Postgres 9.2. But since you have `FOR UPDATE` in the subquery, this is not an option anyway.

It would help quite a bit, if `user_id` was an `integer` instead of `varchar`. (Foreign key to a user table.) Besides faster handling and a smaller table, two integer fit perfectly in a minimum-size index. Your primary key would benefit quite a bit.

Comment: It is true that one of the things we have tried is running ANALYZE manually after the insert, and it appears to help. However we don't know if it is the ANALYZE that helps, or the fact that we give the database time to do whatever it is it's doing (such as flushing pages to disk etc). The reason we're not sure is that the new inserts seem like a small percentage of the total elements (5-7%), is that enough to justify an explicit analyze?

Comment: @xpapad: Most probably yes. It may be a few percent of the total rows, but a huge chunk of the *relevant* rows. Statistic include much more than just the row count. Frequency of values for instance ..

Answer (score 0):

1) Change order of condotions, not sure but I think indexes are not used:

`AND CHUNK_ID IS NULL AND STATE='PENDING'`

for

`STATE='PENDING' AND CHUNK_ID IS NULL`

and

`WHERE wi.STATE='PENDING' AND wi.BULK_ID = $2`

for

`WHERE wi.BULK_ID = $2 AND wi.STATE='PENDING'`

2) If you don't use column `CHUNK_ID` for `select's` then I would suggest adding to index `BASE_BULK_WI_IDX01` condition `WHERE CHUNK_ID IS NULL` - it will result in much smaller index since it's used only for updates.

Also there's no need for column `State` and `User_ID` to be `varchar` - you should use smaller type like `enum` or `integer`. Index would be much smaller, saveing and reading data faster, less disk, processor and other staff resuources would be used.

Comment: The order of conditions is irrelevant. The query planner applies them as it sees fit. SQL is not a procedural language! You other points are good though.

Comment: I wrote the suggestion about indexes based on my expierience with Postgres 8.4, so if planner works diffrently with newer versions it's goog to konw.

Comment: Obviously, I am referring to `1) Change order of conditions`. Your advice in 2) on indexes is good (with some room for improvement).